# Efficiently find lowest sum paths

Tags: algorithm

This is a big ask but I'm a bit stuck!

I am wondering if there is a name for this problem, or a similar one.

I am probably over complicating finding the solution but I can't think of a way without a full brute force exhaustive search (my current implementation). This is not acceptable for the application involved.

I am wondering if there are any ways of simplifying this problem, or implementation strategies I could employ (language/tool choice is open).

Here is a quick description of the problem:

Given **n** sequences of length **k**:

```
a = [0, 1, 1] == [a1, a2, a3]
b = [1, 0, 2] == [b1, b2, b3]
c = [0, 0, 2] == [c1, c2, c3]
```

find paths of length **k** through the sequences as so (i'll give examples starting at a1, but hopefully you get the idea the same paths need to be derived from b1, c1)

```
a1 -> a2 -> a3
a1 -> b1 -> b2
a1 -> b1 -> a2
a1 -> b1 -> c1
a1 -> c1 -> c2
a1 -> c1 -> a2
a1 -> c1 -> b1
```

**I want to know, which path(s) are going to have the lowest sum:**

```
a1 -> a2 -> a3 == 2
a1 -> b1 -> b2 == 1
a1 -> b1 -> a2 == 2
a1 -> b1 -> c1 == 1
a1 -> c1 -> c2 == 0
a1 -> c1 -> a2 == 1
a1 -> c1 -> b1 == 1
```

So in this case, out of the sample **a1 -> c1 -> c2 is the lowest.**

EDIT:

Sorry, just to clear up the rules for deriving the path.
For example you can move from node **a1** to **b2** if you haven't already exhausted **b2**, and have exhausted the previous node in that sequence (**b1**).

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to find the minimum-length path from `a` to `c`? You can solve this by constructing a directed graph and subsequently using [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm).

Comment: It's not clear what constitutes a valid path.

Comment: @MarcClaesen No, it seems he is looking for a shortest (lease weight) path of length k (#nodes) starting from `a1` without restrictions on the target.

Comment: Either way, Dijkstra can solve it. It's just a matter of defining the stopping criterion.

Comment: Is a1, b2, c3 a valid path? What about a1, c1, a1?

Comment: @MarcClaesen Not exactly, dijkstra does not limit itself to the length of the path (#nodes). Some modification will be needed (i.e. normalizing all weights and adding 1 per edge, so paths with less edges are explored first - but that decays to brute force)

Comment: maybe I don't get the problem (it seems to me a1->b2->c3 would be a solution too) but how about finding the smallest number from each sequence and seeing if it is adjacent to the previous/next sequence?

Comment: @amit traditional Dijkstra is basically BFS with a stopping criterion at the destination node. What I meant is simply changing the stopping criterion to having visited `k` nodes, which is basically standard BFS. I know it's not Dijkstra anymore so I made a poor choice of words.

Comment: @Marc: You have to assign edge weights 1 though for it to be correct, and yeah, then it's just a BFS and doesn't help you at all to find the least-weight path

Comment: @Kevin please see my edit hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: _"you can move from node a1 to b2 if you haven't already exhausted b2, and have exhausted the previous node in that sequence (b1)."_ But doesn't this contradict your proposed best path, "a1 -> c1 -> b2"? You travel to b2 without exhausting b1.

Comment: @Kevin *doh* don't write stack overflow questions tired! I did contradict myself, That was wrong. I have edited the example. It is true you cannot move from a1 -> c1 -> b2.

Comment: with the exhaustion requirement, it seems that you can fully describe a path as a list of N integers that sum up to K. The first item in the sequence represents how many elements of `a` you traverse, the second represents how many from `b`, etc. Ex. a1 a2 a3 is [3,0,0]; a1 b1 b2 is [1,2,0]; and b1 a1 b2 is [1,2,0]. Two paths might have the same list description, but they'll have the same sum too, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

Let's assume the arrays are given as a matrix `A` such that each row is identical to one of the original arrays. Your matrix will be of size `(n+1)x(k+1)`, and make sure that `A[_][0] = 0`

Now, use DP to solve it:

```
f(x,y,z) = min  { f(i,y,z-1) | x < i <= n} [union] { f(i+1,0,z) }  + A[x][y]
f(_,_,0) = 0
f(n,k,z) = infinity for each z > 0
```

**Idea:** In each step you can choose to go to each of the following lines (same column) - or go to the next column, while decreasing the number of more nodes needed.

Moving to the next column is done via the dummy index `A[_][0]`, without decreasing number of nodes needed to go more and without cost, since `A[_][0] = 0`.

**Complexity:**

This solution is basically a brute force, but using memorization of each already explored value of `f(_,_,_)` you basically need only to fill a matrix of size `O(n*k^2)`, where each cell takes `O(n)` time to compute on first look- but in practice can be computed iteratively in O(1) per step, because you only need to minimize with the new element in the row<sup>1</sup>. This gives you `O(n*k^2)` - better than brute force.

---

(1) This is done by `min{x1,x2,x3,...,xk} = min{x_k, min{x1,...,k_k-1}}`, and we already know `min{x1,...,k_k-1}`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a modified version of A* algorithm.

1. Copy the matrix and fill it will 0s
2. foreach secondary diagonal m from the last to first

   1. Foreach cell n in m
            4. New matrix's cell n = old matrix cell n minus min(cell bellow n in new matrix, cell to the right of n in the new matrix).
3. Cell 0,0 in the new matrix is the shortest path

***implement A* algorithem over the pseudocode above.